# A way to get parameter pack from tuple / array?

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates, template-meta-programming, constexpr

So, I'm attempting to mess with `constexpr` strings as one will do and really only have this thus far:

```
template<char... CS> struct text {
    static constexpr char c_str[] = {CS...};
    static constexpr int size = sizeof...(CS);

};
```

and so this compiles

```
text<'a','b','c'> t;

std::cout<< t.c_str  <<std::endl;
```

and outputs `'abc'` as expected.

What I'm wondering is if there's a non-convoluted way to do the reverse; have a function that returns a text type with the necessary `char` template arguments given a `char` array.

Comment: You might want to check this: https://isocpp.org/blog/2018/03/text-formatting-at-the-iso-cpp-standards-meeting-in-jacksonville-victor-zve Compile-time strings will benefit from coming evolutions of the standard. Until then, convoluted is the way to go

Comment: Where are you stuck with returning this type?  Your char array is known at compile time, right?

Comment: @DrewDormann I guess I just don't understand how you'd go from a function with a char array argument to a 'text' object with every char from the array passed as the new objects' template argument. What sort of solution would you suggest?

Comment: I suspect that solutions to that will be **very convoluted**.  You are attempting to convert a function parameter -- something that would be inspected at runtime -- into a return type that must be known at compile time.

Comment: Or put another way, functions do not return templates like `text`.  They must return a specific type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not exactly what you asked... and a little convoluted, I suppose... but if you define a `constexpr` function to detect the length of a string

```
constexpr std::size_t strLen (char const * str, std::size_t len = 0U)
 { return *str ? strLen(++str, ++len) : len; }
```

and an helper struct that define the required type

```
template <char const *, typename>
struct foo_helper;

template <char const * Str, std::size_t ... Is>
struct foo_helper<Str, std::index_sequence<Is...>>
 { using type = text<Str[Is]...>; };
```

you can obtain your type passing the string to

```
template <char const * Str>
struct foo : public foo_helper<Str, std::make_index_sequence<strLen(Str)>>
 { };
```

Unfortunately you can't pass a string literal to it in this way

```
foo<"abc">::type
```

but you have to pass from a global variable

```
constexpr char abcVar[] = "abc";
```

and call `foo` using the global variable

```
foo<abcVar>::type
```

This solution uses `std::index_sequence` and `std::make_index_sequence`, available only starting from C++14, but isn't too difficult to write a substitute for they in C++11.

The following is a full working example

```
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <char ... CS>
struct text
 {
   static constexpr char c_str[] = {CS...};
   static constexpr int size = sizeof...(CS);
 };

constexpr std::size_t strLen (char const * str, std::size_t len = 0U)
 { return *str ? strLen(++str, ++len) : len; }

template <char const *, typename>
struct foo_helper;

template <char const * Str, std::size_t ... Is>
struct foo_helper<Str, std::index_sequence<Is...>>
 { using type = text<Str[Is]...>; };


template <char const * Str>
struct foo : public foo_helper<Str, std::make_index_sequence<strLen(Str)>>
 { };

constexpr char abcVar[] = "abc";

int main()
 {
   static_assert(std::is_same<foo<abcVar>::type,
                              text<'a', 'b', 'c'>>{}, "!");
 }
```

Off Topic: I suggest to add an ending zero in `c_str[]`

```
static constexpr char c_str[] = {CS..., 0};
```

if you want use it as the `c_str()` method of `std::string`.